# Triple standardization with triple weighting

Tags: stata, standardization

I have a question about triple standardization and weighting. I came across a published article that standardizes the same data three times. My statistical knowledge is limited, but I am wondering if this makes any sense. Here is the situation: imagine you have a dataset with 40 variables measuring, let’s say, different forms of well-being. What the authors of this article do is first standardize `((var-(mean))/sd)` each of the 40 variables. Then they group the 40 variables into 5 indexes and standardize the indexes. Finally, they combine the five indexes into a single measure and standardize it again. It goes approximately like this:

1. Standardize the raw data (which is on the same scale)

   ```
   foreach var of varlist x1-x40 {
       summ `var’ [aw=weight]
       replace `var’ = (`var’-r(mean))/r(sd)
   }
   ```
2. Combine the raw data into 5 indexes and then standardize again

   ```
   egen Index1=rowtotal(x1…x8)
   …
   egen Index5=rowtotal(x32-x40)

   foreach var of varlist Index1-Index5 {
       summ `var’ [aw=weight]
       replace `var’ = (`var’-r(mean))/r(sd)
   }
   ```
3. After presenting some descriptive evidence using the 5 indexes, the authors combine them into a single measure and then standardize it again.

   ```
   gen Composite=Index1+Index2+Index3+index4-Index5

   foreach var of varlist Composite {
       summ `var’ [aw=weight]
       replace `var’ = (`var’-r(mean))/r(sd)
   }
   ```

My question is: Does this procedure make any sense? Does the triple standardization influence the results (in terms of significance)? And is it correct to use population weights three times?

I am asking these questions because I have a similar dataset as these authors and would like to follow their procedure, but I am not 100% convinced that it is correct.